# Collate information based on other columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

There are 3 columns containing data. Column 'C' contains a list of data in 3 different number formats (in this instance the formats are a 2, 3 or 6 digit number).

Column 'C' will always contain data and column 'A' and 'B' will only contain data if column 'C' is in the incorrect format. Only one of 'A' and 'B' will ever contain data.

I need all the 3 digit numbers in the 'COLLATED' column (column 'D').

I have tried to use an `IF` function as follows to little avail:

```
=IF(AND(A2="-",B2="-"),D2=C2,IF(B2="-",D2=A2,D2=B2))
```

Am I close or completely off the mark?

[image: Example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the 3 digit values display for sure in any one column then the below will do. Place below formula in D2 and drag it down for all the cells you want.

=IF(A2<>"-",A2,IF(B2<>"-",B2,C2))